# How can I salvage these low level items?

Tags: godfall

I'm trying to keep my inventory clean as there are so many items in this game, but for some reason I cannot salvage two low level items:

- this Sword:
  [image]
- and this Life Stone:
  [image]

They have little lock symbol and "Mark for Salvage" button is disabled for them. I checked all my Valorplates and these items are not equipped.

How do I salvage or delete them?

I'm on PS5 and only have Godfall: Challenger Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out these items are used as defaults for all Valorplates. To actually salvage them you will need to unlock all Valorplates first and then unequip these items.